# Expression of generated column 'age' contains a disallowed function: curdate

Tags: mysql

I'm Trying to create a derived attribute using.

`create table hello(dob date,  age int as( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE())));`

and this is the error I'm getting.

`ERROR 3763 (HY000): Expression of generated column 'age' contains a disallowed function: curdate.`

I tried finding what's the issue but couldn't find it.

Comment: It is not helpful to ask why something is or isn't in a language. Anyway that is a question for the designers. Other languages/products/variants are irrelevant. PS This shows no research. [ask] [Help] PS The 1st hit of my 1st google shows this was only recently added to MariaDB.

Comment: You just answered yourself why `MariaDB` was created and is widely used :) (one of the reasons)

Answer (score 4):

From MySQL documentation [13.1.18.7 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.
>
> - Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. **Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition**: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), **NOW()**.

---

As for MariaDB it will fail depending on mode: **VIRTUAL** vs **PERSISTENT/STORED**:

```
-- default
create table hello(
dob date,
age int as( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) ) VIRTUAL 
);
```

vs

```
create table hello(
dob date,
age int as( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) ) PERSISTENT -- STORED
);
```

[db<>fiddle demo - MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c6ae19fcc07be3697160f77b8e78e13d)

[db<>fiddle demo - MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dafc31c0d93dc1dcdc3e2887d351117)